# Actions class in selenium 3.3.1 deprecated looking for solution with contextClick

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created my automation code on Selenium 2.44.0

Following code used to work fine

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element); 
action.build().perform();
```

But now i am getting errors when i try to upgrade to Selenium 3.3.1 version.

Getting following error near important statement:

> The import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions cannot be resolved

Getting following error near contextClick:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Actions cannot be resolved to a    type
> - Actions cannot be resolved to a    type

When i look up for documentation found out that Actions class is deprecated, not sure how we can perform right click to get the context menu.

Comment: as per below answer, re-download and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with **selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar** and it works absolutely fine.

Actions Class still exists in Selenium 3.3.1, as there is no mention of its deprecation in [Selenium 3.3.1 Change Log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG).

Could you please redownload the latest selenium bindings from [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), and rerun your script.

Comment: Hi Apurv, I have selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar in my project Build paths, and i downloaded selenium 3.3.1 again and configured. Still i am getting same error.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply... When you upgraded to the latest version, did you remove the older versions of selenium, if not, please do so. Additionally, I would suggest, delete the older project and create a fresh project (maybe the old project got corrupted), reconfigure and do rerun again

Answer (score 0):

No need to create new project. just remove the old libs and add updated libs only. if you are using pom file (if it is the Maven Project) then right click on project name then click update maven project. then click "Project" on file menu and then clean your project.
It should work then.